# Movie about a chef couple and a little girl

Tags: identify-this-movie, romance

I watched this movie a year ago. I don't remember the name nor the actors in it.

**Plot details:**

- The movie revolves around a woman (female lead) who is the head chef at a restaurant. She is well known for her recipes. Her sister dies in an accident and she takes up the responsibility of raising her sister's 10 year old daughter. She becomes the god mother to the girl. She misses her mother so much. She doesn't like living with her aunt. Female lead tries to impress her with new dishes, but the young girl doesn't talk much with her and eats nothing she cooks. The daughter refuses to tell which food she likes.
- Due to this pressure, she loses her touch and some customer complains about her dish and cooking. The restaurant owner appoints another famous chef (male lead), giving him equal authority over the kitchen.  She doesn't like it. She was jealous of him in the beginning and later on, they love each other. This guy becomes friends with the little girl.  The little girl becomes active and reveals her interest in cooking and the restaurant.
- There's a scene where these three are having fun at home. The setup is like a campfire. Girl learns how to make pancake or pizza (I'm not sure about it).
- In the end, both the chefs resign their job and open a small restaurant.

**Details which would help identify the movie**:

- Genre: Romantic comedy. (There wasn't much comedy in it. The film was a bit serious in the beginning).
- I watched it a year ago. I watched it on TV but don't remember the channel. I don't think it was a new movie when I watched it.
- The movie was not that old. It looked like it was released in mid or late 2000s. I think the movie is American but I don't recognize the nationality of actor and actress.
- It was a live action movie.
- The main actor might be an Italian or a French guy in the movie.

I don't remember the names of the characters or the name of the actors in the film.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like [No Reservations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0481141/combined) from 2007 with Catherine Zeta-Jones    and Aaron Eckhart.

> **Kate is a terrific chef** at a Manhattan restaurant, sent to therapy by the restaurant owner because she is cold, unyielding, rule-bound, and a pain in the neck. Kate's world is flipped over when **her only sister dies and her ten-year-old niece, Zoe, comes to live with her.** As Kate struggles to be a parent to a grief-stricken child, the one world she used to control - the restaurant kitchen - is changed utterly by **the restaurant's hiring a second chef, the loose, operatic, Italian-trained Nick, who claims it's an honor to work in Kate's kitchen but who she suspects wants to replace her.** Can the music of Puccini and the taste of good pasta soften Kate's heart?

The trailer:

Comment: Damn it Walt...do you have an alert or something?

Comment: Sure, I'm summoned by the overwhelming presence in the ether of good details in an ID question. Who isn't?

Comment: I coulda answer this, but chose instead to edit the question ;-)